# Convert Windows Batch to run on CentOS?

Tags: command-line, centos, notepad++

I got my current script:

```
@echo off 
c: 
REM Forces to change to C drive 
cd / 
REM Forces to start at c:\ instead of a random folder 
cd Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\ 
REM Selects the work folder 
echo current directory = %cd% 
REM Displays the work folder 
set /p Folder= Please insert domain name? 
REM Asks user for folder name to save in 

if not exist %Folder% ( 
    mkdir %Folder% 
    cd %Folder% 
    break>"CSR.txt" 
    break>"KEY.txt" 
    start notepad++ "CSR.txt" 
    start notepad++ "KEY.txt" 
    REM Makes the folder and requested files , also opens the files in notepad++ 
 ) else ( 
    echo %Folder% already exists, creating date folder 
    cd %Folder% 
    mkdir %date:~-10,2%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-4,4%-%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2% 
    cd %date:~-10,2%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-4,4%-%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2% 
    break>"CSR.txt" 
    break>"KEY.txt" 
    start notepad++ "CSR.txt" 
    start notepad++ "KEY.txt" 
    REM If previous folder already exists make a date folder , also opens the files  in notepad++
    pause  
)
```

(Don't mind the REM lines, this is my first script so had to add some pointers for myself)

Now I want this script to run on my (CentOS) server but I have no clue on how to make this work.

Can anybody point me in the right direction / help me out converting this to CentOS script(s) ?

Comment: Your script seems to be a batch script from Windows, CentOS is linux, they aren't compatible. Why did you tagged it as [notepad++]? Please edit your question and clarify it.

Comment: @MátéJuhász thank you for replying, I added notepad++ to this as I've used it to open the files my script has made.

Answer (score 0):

CentOS is a Linux Distribution based on Red Hat and as such can not directly execute a Windows batch script. You will have to convert it to a format that is executable by said Distribution. An example could be a bash script and it could look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Documents
echo Current Directory = $(pwd)
read -p "Please insert domain name?" folder

if [ ! -d "$folder" ]; then
    mkdir $folder
    cd $folder
    touch CSR.txt
    touch KEY.txt

    vi CSR.txt
    vi KEY.txt
else
    currentDate=$(date +%F)
    mkdir $currentDate
    cd $currentDate

    touch CSR.txt
    touch KEY.txt

    vi CSR.txt
    vi KEY.txt
fi
```

The above script shortens the `currentDate` to be just the date in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Depending on your actual goal with this it's advisable to put a lot more work into it. You're creating a CSR and KEY text file which hints that you want to do something along the lines of setting up a CA? There's plenty to take into consideration with this and it would out of scope of your question but you really need to read up on it!

In addition I made a suggestion for change for your initial post. You did some really funky things with your editing and your indention was all over the place. On stackexchange it's usually supported to prefix a space/tab to mark a block as code. Which in this case really would help.